# OWD override the Permission set?

Tags: permission-sets, owd, sharing-sets

I have a object with setting public read only but with permission set can i override it? Like if i want to delete or edit other records if user has a permission set assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Modify All](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm) permission for the particular object would give you access to edit and delete record owned by other users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can give edit and delete permissions as needed on the permission set.

Answer (score 0):

**Key concepts:**

- The Organization Wide Defaults for an object define which records a user has visibility to.
- Sharing rules can extend that access to additional records for that object.
- The user's profile defines what actions can be performed on the records the user has visibility to. Actions: Read/Edit/Create/Delete)
- The user's permission set(s) can extend (though not take away -- exception: muting permissions) the actions that can be performed on the records that are visible to the user.
- Some permissions in the profile/permissionSet supersede the sharing rules/record visibility; notably `View All`, `Modify All` on the object; and `View All Data` / `Modify All Data`

Best practice is usually to start with minimum privileges: {record sharing, object permissions} and then add sharing rules/object permissions as needed.

For example, you could start with an OWD of `Private` and all users (except sysads) with Profile `Minimum Access - Salesforce` and then, through Sharing Rules, Permission Sets and Permission Set Groups build up a suite of tightly-controlled access to records and operations upon them.

It is easy to add permissions/access; it is much harder (config/testing time-wise) to start taking away permissions/access in an existing org